# Print Post Parent Title

Tags: functions

I'm trying to print the posts' parent title on the page as well as the post title for that page. This is how my content-page.php template currently renders the page title.

```
the_title( '<header class="entry-header"><h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1></header><!-- .entry-header -->' );
```

I realise I can retrieve the posts' parent title by doing this:

```
$parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
echo $parent_title;
```

Is there anyway I can slip that code in between the_title parameters, so my parent title and my post title are both wrapped by that `h1` element?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can just add a check:

```
if ( ! empty ( $post->post_parent ) )
{
    $parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
    echo "<h1>$parent_title</h1>";
}
```

or use `setup_postdata()`:

```
setup_postdata( $post->post_parent );
the_title( /* arguments here*/ );
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just filter `the_title`:

```
function wpse140502_filter_page_title( $title ) {
    // only do something on static pages
    // and on the main query
    if ( is_page() && is_main_query() ) {
        // let's see if the current page has a parent
        global $post;
        if ( 0 != $post->post_parent ) {
            // Set this to whatever you want
            $delimiter = ': ';
            // Append post-parent title to title and return it
            return get_the_title( $post->post_parent ) . $delimiter . $title;
        }
    }
    // return title
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse140502_filter_page_title' );
```

Comment: This filter is used on many places, including widgets and nav menus.

Comment: Let me fix that

Answer (score 0):

You could just output the header around the title without using the `$before` and `$after` parameters:

```
if ( get_the_title() ) {
    global $post;

    echo '<header class="entry-header"><h1 class="entry-title">';
    echo get_the_title() . ' - ' . get_the_title( $post->post_parent );
    echo '</h1></header>';
}
```

If you insist on using `$before` and `$after`, just pass the parent title to either one of the arguments:

```
the_title( '<header class="entry-header"><h1 class="entry-title">' . get_the_title( $post->post_parent ), '</h1></header><!-- .entry-header -->' );
```

or

```
the_title( '<header class="entry-header"><h1 class="entry-title">', get_the_title( $post->post_parent ) . '</h1></header><!-- .entry-header -->' );
```